# Python: if in, then match on field of row found in

Tags: python, list, if-statement

The title may be a little confusing, but I was wondering if there was a way to us "if in" to look at other fields in an array once it is matched. I figure if there isn't something built-in, i'll just have to step it all through manually instead of using is-in.

Anyway, my code looks like this:

```
csv = csv.reader(response)
query = con.fetchall()

for row in query:
    if row[1] in csv:
       do some stuff
    else:
       do some other stuff
```

Is there a way for the first if to basically be "if row[1] in csv and matched csv[4] == TRUE: do some stuff"?

So basically like two stage matching, if it exists and if one of the fields equals something else.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what's wrong if you just use `if row[1] in csv and csv[4] == True`

Comment: I think maybe he means `if row[1] in csv and row[1] == csv[4]:`, maybe?

Comment: I would be very surprised if the csv reader object supported `in` and slicing.  All sequences are iterable, but not all iterables are sequences.  If you want random access to your csv data, you'll need to read the whole thing into memory first.

Comment: the csv reader returns an iterable, but what you need is to rollout the iterable into a list i.e. `rows = list(reader(response))`. We will need to know more about what a csv row looks like, it looks like you want to match row[1] to any column within the csv rows (is this correct), if so your code needs to be changed quite a bit. More details on what you are doing will help figure this out.

Comment: csv is a downloaded file from a web page, which is a CSV that I am getting through urllib2 nand then using csv.reader to get it to be used. Basically, first I need to check to see if row[1] is in CSV, then, if it is found I want to check the element in the CSV that it was found on to see what the value of CSV[4] is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first need to load the full csv, currently you are just iterating through it. Also it seems what you want to do is look for row[1] somewhere in a csv row, your code is currently looking for a full csv row that matches row[1] which I doubt is correct. Here is my answer to what I think you are asking.

```
rows = list(reader(response))
query = con.fetchall() # this one you can iterate through, I am just copying what you had
for row in query:
    rs = filter(lambda r: row[1] in r, rows)
    for r in rs:
        if r[4]:
            pass # do some stuff (here)
            break
    else: # this is a for ... else loop
        pass # do some other stuff
```

Again I am making a lot of assumptions about your actual problem ... if you clarify your question I maybe able to find a more efficient solution.

Comment: I think a final answer is likely to involve using `index` on the loaded csv data rather than filtering it each time.  Depending on what the actual problem is.

Comment: I was initially using index, then realized that there is no way rows.index(row[1]) would match anything, since rows is a list of lists while row[1] is going to be some sort of literal (int, string ...). As the question is originally coded though, index does seem like it should be used but I doubt it will be usable here.

Comment: I responded above, before I saw this. I think this might work, i'm a little new to Python, but I'll have a go with it. To clarify, CSV is a CSV I am downloading from a website through urllib2, I get the response and user csv.reader() to create the 'csv' variable. I have a list of tuples in 'query' that are IP Addresses and some other information. In the CSV are a list of IP addresses and a field (csv[4]) that may be set to True or False. I want to iterate through the CSV for each IP in 'query' and if it is matched, then check that element of CSV to see if csv[4] is TRUE or FALSE. Clear as mud?

Comment: This is what I ended up going with, or something similar. I think it should work for me in the end, I just have some other logic to work out.

Comment: what column is the ip address in the CSV? right now this code looks at every column of the csv for each row, if you know the column you can make it a little more efficient.